# Specializing a Template With a Return Type Derived by decltype in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, template-specialization, function-templates

Given the following code:

```
template<typename ValueType>
decltype(ValueType{} == ValueType{}) Compare(const ValueType& value, const ValueType& expected)
{
    return value == expected;
}

template<>
decltype(float{} == float{}) Compare<float>(const float& value, const float& expected)
{
    return std::abs(value - expected) < 1e-4F;
}
```

I would expect the call `Compare(13.0F, 42.0F)` to correctly call the specialization, [which it does on gcc](https://ideone.com/1ToJon). But it fails to on [visual-studio-2017](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2017). I get the error:

> error C2912: explicit specialization `bool Compare<float>(const float &,const float &)` is not a specialization of a function template

Is there something I can do to help guide [visual-studio](/questions/tagged/visual-studio)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Purely to appease VC++, you may extract the return type as another template argument.

```
template<typename ValueType, typename RetType = decltype(ValueType{} == ValueType{})>
RetType Compare(const ValueType& value, const ValueType& expected)
{
    return value == expected;
}

template<>
decltype(float{} == float{}) Compare<float>(const float& value, const float& expected)
{
    return std::abs(value - expected) < 1e-4F;
}
```

That makes VC++ accept the code.

Comment: I've tried just about everything I can think of short of adding a return parameter :( I wanted to avoid adding template parameters... but this does seem to be the only viable solution.